# Center a circle in other device

Tags: flutter, dart

Thank you for your solution I did it I would like with this situation center vertically my circle is it possible? if yes how can I do please

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Text 1", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Text 2", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Text 3", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                    radius:   30,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Carle, check out my answer, your solution is under **ANSWER 2.0** section of my answer. Let me know if that worked for you

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways you can do this.

**1. USING CENTER AND CONTAINER**

```
     Container(
        height: double.infinity, // this parent height takes up the full height of the device
        width: double.infinity, // this parent width takes up the full width of the device
        child: Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            radius: 50
          )
        )
      )
```

**2. IF YOU WANT TO USE STACK**

```
     Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              child: Center(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                  radius: 50,
                )
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      )
```

**OR**

If you don't want to use `Positioned`, then it is completely fine. You can only use `Center()` inside your stack and achieve this, unless, you have the specific requirements for `Positioned`

```
      //This is same as the 2nd case, but no Poisitioned widget is used
      Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Simple center, and you will get the same data
            Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                radius: 50,
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      )
```

In both the ways you will achieve your goal. The screenshot reveals the result, which we get after using any of the above codes.

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE]

**ANSWER 2.0**

You have to just edit the question in order to ask your problem **Carle**. In order to achieve what you want, the below code will help you achieve this.

Before that, I am confirming your requirement => **You need the circle to come vertically centered as per the device with other widgets pointed to top**

```
        Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              // This is different widgets, which represents another entity
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Text 1", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Text 2", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Text 3", textScaleFactor: 2,),
                  )
                ]
              ),
              // This comes overlapped, and uses the whole height of the device
              // and comes vertically centered which you want
              Center(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                  radius:   30,
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
```

**RESULT YOU WILL GET**

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE]

Do give it a read about [Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), it will surely help you understand more about Flutter. It is more of like `relative-position` in `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the CircleAvatar by Center and then by Container with width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and this container inside the Positioned and set only top position.

Answer (score 0):

you can try ...

```
positioned.fill(
  child:Center( 
    child:CircleAvatar()
   )
)
```

Comment: karam chand gandhi, i just had say it ;)